# How can we have a single title for the whole glossaries in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, symbols, glossaries, acronyms

I'm using glossary package and perl.exe for the abbreviations and symbols. I want to have a single chapter heading (Nomenklatur) in the table of contents but a number of glossary titles (Abkürzungen, Formelzeichen, Griechische Symbols, Indizes) in the description as shown in the figure (1st and 2nd) below. However, with the current code, I have all the glossary tiles in the table of contents (figure 3rd). Could someone help me to to do this?

[image: What I want in ToC]

[image: What I want in print section]

[image: What I have now in ToC]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, twoside, openright, parskip,fleqn]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[toc,sort=def,xindy,order=letter,style=long,acronym,nopostdot,nonumberlist,nogroupskip,sanitizesort=true]{glossaries}

\newglossary[ch1]{greek}{ch2}{ch3}{Griechische Symbole}
\newglossary[ah1]{indizes}{ah2}{ah3}{Indizes}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{mr}{name={$m_\textrm{r}$},description={rotierende Ersatzmasse des
        Kurbeltriebes}}

\newacronym{ABHE}{ABHE}{Einspritzbeginn Haupteinspritzung}

\newglossaryentry{alpha}{name={$ \alpha$},description={Wärmeübergangskoeffizient, Steigungswinkel}, type=greek}
    
\newglossaryentry{Arbeitsspiel}{name={Asp},description={Arbeitsspiel},type=indizes}

\begin{document}
    
    \tableofcontents    
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[title=Abkürzungen,type=\acronymtype]
    \printglossary[title=Formelzeichen]
    \printglossary[type=greek]
    \printglossary[type=indizes]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try to add (after the call of `\glsaddall`) the commands of `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenklatur}` and `\setglossarysection{section}`. The first one adds manually a single line to your TOC. The second one instructs glossary to handle the printed glossaries as sections (or subsection, subsubsection, you get the idea). And btw: you don't need to set `title` and `toctitle` if they are identical.

Comment: @Venez Thank you! And more thing, is there any way to suppress the section form appearing in ToC?

Comment: Of course, only thing to do is to drop the `toc` option in your package call (the very first thing you actually did).